# Trigger jQuery event on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
// change the number of finished and missing assets
$('.add-requirements .overall-status .status-dropdown li').live('click', function() {
    var remaining_titles = $('.item-section.finished').length;
    $('.add-requirements .remaining-titles').text(remaining_titles);
});
```

It fires whenever a status dropdown is changed. How would I also make it fire when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand you want to update the remaining count on page load and I assume that the `finished` status is pre setted on the desired elements.

I'll go about this in another way

```
$('.add-requirements .overall-status .status-dropdown li').live('click', updateRemaining);
updateRemaining()

function updateRemaining(){
    var remaining_titles = $('.item-section.finished').length;
    $('.add-requirements .remaining-titles').text(remaining_titles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just chain on a `trigger('click')` to trigger a click on first pageload :

```
$('.add-requirements .overall-status .status-dropdown li').live('click', function() {
    var remaining_titles = $('.item-section.finished').length;
    $('.add-requirements .remaining-titles').text(remaining_titles);
}).trigger('click');
```

But you should really be using `on()`

```
$('closest_non_dynamic_parent').on('click', 'your_freakishly_long_selector', function() {
```

Comment: This seems to make the event fire like 5,000 times when I try this way.

Comment: @adeneo the problem here is it will trigger the click event on each of the `li` elements which may not be what the OP wants, it looks like the OP want to update the remaining count

Answer (score 0):

A bit more verbose, but here is what worked for me:

```
var remaining_titles_section = $('.add-requirements .remaining-titles');
remaining_titles_section.text($('.item-section.finished').length);
$('.add-requirements .overall-status .status-dropdown li').live('click', function() {
    var remaining_titles = $('.item-section.finished').length;
    remaining_titles_section.text(remaining_titles);
});
```